# What are the ASTERIX CAT010 message types 005 and higher?

Tags: avionics, asterix

I am analyzing some surface radar recording data under Asterix CAT010 category. The document from Eurocontrol shows that there are 4 standardized message formats under this category:

- 001 Target Report
- 002 Start of Update Cycle
- 003 Periodic Status Message
- 004 Event-triggered Status Message

However, I could find some other types from 005 to even a few hundred.
May I know what are these message types referring to?

Comment: What kind of ASTERIX decoder are you using? Where does the data come from, who is the manufacturer of the SMR, which radar model? Can you add a few messages (in hexadecimal notiation) so I can have a look?

Comment: Obelix? OBELIX!?

Comment: @DeltaLima Thanks for your suggestion. Finally, the issue is solved. I got a help from the author of this repository. https://github.com/CroatiaControlLtd/asterix There is some issue previously when decoding the CAT10 data. Now it is corrected.

Comment: @Peter It is a batch of data following the Asterix format from Eurocontrol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, it is solved. It is not about the data issue but some decoding issue. I am using an asterix-decoder in python from https://github.com/CroatiaControlLtd/asterix.
Based on the help of its author, Damir Salantic. "There was a bug in the presentation of hexdata in case when the old format of asterix is used. Old format has several Data Records in Data Block."
Now the issue is fixed and the decoder repository is updated the decoded data is following the format from Eurocontrol.

Comment: Hi Yicheng, thank you for taking the time to come back here and answering your own question.